# Store data from an array and use it later

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I had this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943322/use-sheet-name-as-a-loop-parameter/45951774?noredirect=1#comment78930296_45951774) which [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) helped me to solve it (thanks again for that), but now I'm struggling with a different one. The following script will count how many times a client code will appear on another Spreadsheet using as a second condition yesterday date.

```
   function countSheets() 
 { 
  var vA = appSh();
  var td = Utilities.formatDate(subDaysFromDate(new Date(),2), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var mbs=getAllSheets();
  //var s='';
  for (var i=2;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][12]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    for(var key in mbs)
    {
      if(vA[i][0]==key && d==td) 
      {
        mbs[key]+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  return mbs;
}
```

Then I have the below code which will search in the main spreadsheet (a table) a string and when was found will return row number, also will search for the date yesterday and return the column number. Based on these information I'll get the range where I need to paste the count result from the first script.

```
    function runScript() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var mbs=countSheets();
  for(var key in mbs)
  {
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(key);
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      if(vA[i][1]=='Total Number of Applications')
      {
        var nr=i;
        break;//by terminating as soon as we find a match we should get improved performance.  Which is something you cant do in a map.
      }             
    }
    if(typeof(nr)!='undefined')//If we don't find a match this is undefined
    {
      var today=subDaysFromDate(new Date(),2).setHours(0,0,0,0);
      for(var i=0;i<vA[3].length;i++)
      {
        if(vA[3][i])//Some cells in this range have no contents
        {
          if(today.valueOf()==new Date(vA[3][i]).valueOf())
          {
            sh.getRange(nr+1,i+1,1,1).setValue(Number(mbs[key]));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sh;
}
```

**PROBLEM:** I have 24 rows on the main Spreadsheet. So I will need to write the same script 24 times. As example, I need to count Total Number of Applications, Total Number of Calls, Number of Live Adverts and so on. If I do this it will exceed execution time since each script takes on average 25 seconds to run.

I did some researches on this website and internet and read about storing values and re-use them over and over. At the moment my script will have to go every time through the same file and count for each condition.

**Q1:** Is there any chance to create another array that contain all those strings from the second script?

**Q2:** How to use PropertiesService or anything else to store data and don't have to run over and over `getValues()` ? I've read Google Documentation but couldn't understand that much from it.

I hope it all make sense and can fix this problem.

My best regards,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## My Approach to your Problem

You probably should write it for a couple of rows and then look at the two of them and see what is unique to each one.  What is unique about each one is what you have to figure out how to store or access via an external function call.

The issue of time may require that you run these functions separately.  I have a dialog which I use to load databases which does exactly that.  It loads 800 lines and waits for 10 seconds then loads another 800 lines and wait for ten seconds and keeps doing that until there are no more lines.  True it takes about 10 minutes to do this but I can be doing something else while it's working so I don't really care how long it takes.  I do care about minimizing my impact to the Google Server though and so I don't run something like this just for fun.

By the way the 10 second delay is external to the gs function.

Comment: The only thing it's slowing down the script is that it has to get Applications Sheets values for every single sheet. Run Sheet1 -> getValues() -> loop, Run Sheet -> getValues() -> loop ... so I need a solution to store all values from that sheet on re-use them.

Comment: The reality is that you can't getValues() for all sheets all at one time.  So getting them all at one time and storing them in an array won't really do you that much good.  It sounds like your not going to get all of this done in 6 minutes so I guess I'd move on to thinking about another alternative.  [`"You can't always get what you want.But if you try, sometimes you might find You get what you need"`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkGrkNu6mDg)